# Как отправить CURLом POST запрос и обработать его?

Tags: php, post, curl, codeigniter

Доброго времени!

Использую CI. Пытаюсь отправить POST запрос на сторонний URL, но ничего не получается. Ошибок нет, но обработчик не принимает POST запрос.

**Файл контролера:**

```
public function sci_advcash()
{
    // Send POST request

    $url = "http://example.com/post.php";  

    $post_data = array (  
            "amount" => "100",
            "method" => "ADV Cash",  
            "date" => "15 Januare",
            "adv_id" => "#234rt34t"
    );  

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    // указываем, что у нас POST запрос  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
    // добавляем переменные  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);  

    $output = curl_exec($ch);  

    curl_close($ch);  

    echo $output; 

}
```

**Обработчик, который должен записать POST в текстовый файл:**

```
<?php
// строка, которую будем записывать
$text = $_POST;

// открываем файл, если файл не существует,
//делается попытка создать его
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");

// записываем в файл
fwrite($fp, $text);

// закрываем
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

$_POST является массивом, вы пытаетесь записать в файл массив, вместо строки, вам нужно изменить обработчик, например так:

```
// строка, которую будем записывать
$text = print_r($_POST, true);

// открываем файл, если файл не существует,
//делается попытка создать его
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "w");

// записываем в файл
fwrite($fp, $text);

// закрываем
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: можно даже сократить: `file_put_contents('file.txt', print_r($_POST, true));`